# How to send email using localhost/xampp?

Tags: php, email, xampp, localhost

i am newbie in php,i want to send email using localhost/xampp and i tried everything but no luck.i tried  Change php.ini file ,sendmail, sendmail path,port and cofig my gmail details (gmail id,Password).Done everything mentioned in the tutorials in stackoverflow.

my email code

```
    $to= 'email@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .     'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .     'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 
    $ans = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    var_dump($ans);
```

Comment: Are you trying to send mail to gmail id ? If so, check your spam box of gmail.

Comment: ya man....but mail not recived

Comment: i have the same doubt tried everything in that ....but still no luck

Comment: Not fully sure of what your problem is, but it's worth noting that Gmail requires authentication, thus you cannot use its services with plain `mail()` funcion. You need a full-fledged third-party mail library.

Comment: http://www.websnippetz.blogspot.in/2013/01/send-email-from-xampp-localhost.html